# save image after some data written on that image

Tags: php, jquery, image

Hi all
i am displaying an image in a div and content in another div.using jquery draggable method, i placed the content in that div on the image. Now i want to save that image with content as an image. Is it possible? please answer this as it is important

Comment: save that image with content as an image ??? what it means..Abhimanyu please clear your question

Comment: So, you have an image and over it you have content. You need all that content that you have over the image saved as an image. Am I getting it right?

Comment: i understood the question but have no idea how todo such a thing... im sure its not possible with just jquery, i would think all the data would need tobe posted into php then use some gd functions to measure and manipulate the content into an image

Comment: @teodor talov: you got it correct

Comment: @diEcho : say i have an image, on that image i wrote some text(say Welcome). Now i want to save that image which the text welcome should appear on that image

Comment: @Abhimanyu u should learn **PHP GD library** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: thanks. i will check it. I have a doubt on jquery draggable and droppable. I am dropping the data on that image using jquery, but while saving that image, i am losing that data even though i am using droppable method in jquery

Comment: @Abhimanyu jQuery Droppable has absolutely nothing to do with saving text into images. Getting something like this working is a lot more complicated than you seem to imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to do this, but it's not trivial and I won't post all the code necessary to do it. Instead, I'll give you some pointers:

- You can't save the added text "as is" client-side. That's not possible. You could take a screenshot of it, but that's probably not what you want.
- Instead, you need to save the text value and the position and size of where the text is placed relative to the image.

  - Use relative values, e.g. `x = 0.3242, y = 0.5123, width = 0.5123, height = 0.12`, where `x = 0, y = 0` is the top left corner of the image and `x = 1, y = 1` the bottom right corner, width and height similarily representing a fraction of the image size.
- POST this information to the server and recreate the same effect by baking the text into the image using, for example, [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).
- For finding the right font size to use, futz around with [`imagettfbbox`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) until you have found the closest equivalent in size to the target coordinates.
- Use [`imagettftext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) for writing the text into the image.